# Oxygen and xmllint xsd validating differently—which is correct?

Tags: xml, xsd, saxon, xmllint

When I work on a particular XSD file with Oxygen, the XSD works fine for validating our XML.

When I use xmllint, it says that it can't compile the XSD because it is not valid.

One error we are getting when validating with xmllint is:

```
./schema.xsd:6: element element: Schemas parser error : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element': Invalid value for maxOccurs (must be 0 or 1).
WXS schema ./s.xsd failed to compile
```

The schema is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" vc:minVersion="1.1" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType mixed="true" name="foo">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="bar" type="bar"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Why are Oxygen and xmllint validating differently? Which one is right?

> Detail that might help: Oxygen uses Saxon and xmllint uses libxml

### Edit

Updated question with minimal, complete, verifiable example.

Comment: If you're planning on doing something with your schema in production, then the one which is "right" is whatever will run with your software.

Comment: Why the *slightly modified* offending line?  If you're asking about an intricate issue involving spec compliance, then create a **specific and complete** [mcve], or you're wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Disagree: One can be right based on the W3C recommendations, or they both can be if the spec is ambiguous.   Implementations don't define what's right.

Comment: @kjhughes I actually agree with you, I wasn't saying anything about which technically follows a proper standard.  But we have some really old code (think 15 years old Java 3 code), which follows standards which are not considered bad and obsolete.  But to get our code to work, we needed XML which behaved that way.

Comment: @kjhughes yes, my question is specific and complete. I changed the `name` and `type` properties so I don't get in legal trouble for posting exact code owned by a client. But I changed them in a consistent way that doesn't effect the question I'm asking at all.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:  Ok, understood.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen both run with our software. Validation is a manual part of our workflow right now and we can use either tool (even better if we can use both).

Comment: @kjhughes I don't think this is implementation-dependent. I tried to read the spec and it looks like Oxygen might be wrong, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @mheiber:  You needn't tell us about sanitizing; you do need to post a MCVE, which in this case means a small XML document and a small XSD that exhibit the inconsistent behavior you describe.  You've not done that yet.  (It's really your job, not ours.)  Once you do, someone here will be happy to roll up their sleeves and tell you whether one or the other implementations are wrong, or whether the spec is ambiguous such that they both can be right.

Comment: @kjhughes the problem I'm facing here is that I know so little about XSD that I can't even make a valid document on my own and am banging my head against the wall. I can't come up with a more complete example. Do you want me to delete the question?

Comment: In your question, xmllint error shows a namespace that is not XML Schema namespace `(http://www.w3.org/2001/<X not present here>MLSchema)`. Is this the namespace present in xmllint output or is it a typo while copy/pasting the error message to the question?

Comment: @sergioFC, not sure how that copy-paste mistake slipped in. I updated the question to fix the typo.

Answer (score 4):

Without a MCVE, this is only a guess...

The error,

> Invalid value for maxOccurs (must be 0 or 1).

typically comes up when children of `xs:all` have `maxOccurs` of `unbounded` under XSD 1.0.

If this is your problem, then an xmllib-based validator such as xmllint will rightly complain because it implements XSD 1.0, whereas a saxon-based validator such as Oxygen will not complain when validating according to XSD 1.1.

If this isn't exactly your problem, it may point the way to another XSD 1.0 vs XSD 1.1 difference that does account for the behavior you're seeing.  I would recommend you configure Oxygen to specifically use XSD 1.0 in any event to see if that doesn't eliminate the difference you're seeing.

Comment: That was my thought too, but there's no sign of an xs:all in this sample.

Comment: Right, but lack of an MCVE limits our visibility into what else might be in play.

Comment: @MichaelKay @kjhughes, the elements for which they are errors are under `xs:all`. Apologies for the incomplete example. I'll take the recommended troubleshooting step and also try again to complete the example for future SO readers. Thanks

Comment: It looks like xmllint is 1.1 compatible, since it doesn't fail on other XSD 1.1 features (for example, `xsd:override`). Oxygen barfs on even my minimal example (above) for another reason (`undefined type foo`) even though xmllint doesn't complain about that. Very confusing.

Comment: xmllint does ***not*** support XSD 1.1.   Furthermore, your "MCVE" is not a MCVE because it references an undefined type, rendering it useless as a test of this issue because so no conformant XSD 1.0 or 1.1 processor will accept it anyway.

Comment: Anyway, it seems that [inside xs:all maxOccurs can only be 0 or 1 even under XSD 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#element-all)

Comment: @Ale: It's not the allowed values of `maxOccurs` for `xs:all` but rather its children that are at issue here.